# Primefaces 3.5 p:fileUpload lose value

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, primefaces, upload

I have one issue with my p:fileUpload.
I have one add button that adds rows with p:fileUpload.
I add one p:fileUpload and select on file (without save) and after the selection if I press again the add button the previously selected value disappears.
Is any proper way to solve that issue?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Im not sure if anyone can help you, PrimeFaces 3.5 is almost 10 years old.

Comment: You are right but my job projects are all legacy and use old technologies.